# Failed to connect to remote MySQL server via proxy

Tags: networking, mysql, amazon-web-services, proxy, unix

I am trying to use an R tool in which RMySQL is one of the package being used. I am working this on ubuntu behind a corporate proxy but having the following issue for three days persistently.

> Error in .local(drv, ...) : Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'locuscompare-us-west-2a.xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (111) Warning message: In rm(config) : object 'config' not found

Here are the source codes of the above-mentioned R tool.

```
get_position=function(x, genome = c('hg19','hg38')){

data(config)
on.exit(rm(config))

conn = RMySQL::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),"locuscompare",config$b,config$c,config$a)
on.exit(RMySQL::dbDisconnect(conn))

stopifnot('rsid' %in% colnames(x))

genome = match.arg(genome)

cmd = sprintf("select rsid, chr, pos from tkg_p3v5a_%s where rsid in ('%s')",genome,paste0(x$rsid,collapse="','"))
res = DBI::dbGetQuery(conn = conn, statement = cmd)
y=merge(x,res,by='rsid')
return(y)}
```

I have already tried some solutions answered in stack overflow, such as installing MySQL, assigning users' privilege, editing bind-address in configuration file, but it still does not work.

I thought at first it was an issue related to the lacking of MySQL server and AWS account on my device and also some issues in source codes. But, when I use that tool on my mac with home Wi-Fi, it is working like a charm without any installation of MySQL server and creation of AWS account. Obviously, this might be a proxy issue. I still need to use it on my work PC because of input data privacy issue.

Does it mean I need to create an AWS account and adjust the network setting inside of it to access MySQL server on this URL 'locuscompare-us-west-2a.cvocub39nnri.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com'? (Sorry that I am very new to AWS and MySQL.)

I appreciate if you could let me know how to connect to remote MySQL server behind a corporate proxy.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault.  The error says "object "config" not found".  Where is this config mentioned?

Comment: 'get_position=function(x, genome = c('hg19','hg38')){

    data(config)
    on.exit(rm(config))

    conn = RMySQL::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),"locuscompare",config$b,config$c,config$a)
    on.exit(RMySQL::dbDisconnect(conn))

    stopifnot('rsid' %in% colnames(x))' from this source (https://github.com/boxiangliu/locuscomparer/blob/master/R/locuscompare.R)

Comment: Please include that code in your post.